# Tensorflow cnn error: logits and labels must be same size:

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create a CNN using Tensorflow that classifies images into **16 classes**.

My original image size is 72x72x1, and my network is structured like this:

```
# Network
n_input  = dim  
n_output = nclass  # 16
weights  = {
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32], stddev=0.1)),
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64], stddev=0.1)),
    'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([9*9*128, 1024], stddev=0.1)),
    'wd2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_output], stddev=0.1))
}
biases   = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32], stddev=0.1)),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64], stddev=0.1)),
    'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024], stddev=0.1)),
    'bd2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_output], stddev=0.1))
}
```

Here is my conv net function:

```
def conv_basic(_input, _w, _b, _keepratio):
# Input
_input_r = tf.reshape(_input, shape=[-1, 72, 72, 1])

# Conv1
_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(
        tf.nn.conv2d(_input_r, _w['wc1'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        , _b['bc1']))
_pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(_conv1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
mean, var = tf.nn.moments(_pool1, [0, 1, 2])
_pool1 = tf.nn.batch_norm_with_global_normalization(_pool1, mean, var, 1., 0., 1e-7, 0)
_pool_dr1 = tf.nn.dropout(_pool1, _keepratio)

# Conv2
_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(
        tf.nn.conv2d(_pool_dr1, _w['wc2'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        , _b['bc2']))
_pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(_conv2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
mean, var = tf.nn.moments(_pool2, [0, 1, 2])
_pool2 = tf.nn.batch_norm_with_global_normalization(_pool2, mean, var, 1., 0., 1e-7, 0)
_pool_dr2 = tf.nn.dropout(_pool2, _keepratio)

# Vectorize
_dense1 = tf.reshape(_pool_dr2, [-1, _w['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])

# Fc1
_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(_dense1, _w['wd1']), _b['bd1']))
_fc_dr1 = tf.nn.dropout(_fc1, _keepratio)

# Fc2
_out = tf.add(tf.matmul(_fc_dr1, _w['wd2']), _b['bd2'])

# Return everything
out = {
    'input_r': _input_r,
    'conv1': _conv1,
    'pool1': _pool1,
    'pool1_dr1': _pool_dr1,
    'conv2': _conv2,
    'pool2': _pool2,
    'pool_dr2': _pool_dr2,
    'dense1': _dense1,
    'fc1': _fc1,
    'fc_dr1': _fc_dr1,
    'out': _out
}
return out
```

When I try to run this, I get an error: `"tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[6,16] labels_size=[1,16]"`

on the line `cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(_pred, y))`

I've tried changing the wd1 weight values around, and apart from saying that requested shape requires a multiple of xxx, it just changes the values in the brackets.

These values (especially 6) seem very arbitrary, idk where they are coming from. It would be nice for someone to explain to me how FC layer neuron amounts are chosen, as it also seems a bit arbitrary.

Thanks

EDIT: My full code https://gist.github.com/EricZeiberg/f0b138d859b9ed00ce045dc6b341e0a7

Answer (score 3):

Given your code (and guessing what is missing in it), I think you have these parameters and results (correct me if wrong):

- `batch_size`: 1
- `num_classes`: 16
- labels `y`: type int, shape `[batch_size, 1]`
- outputs `_pred`: type float32, **should be** shape `[batch_size, num_classes]`

---

In your code, you only use 2 max pooling, which reduce the input feature map from `[1, 72, 72, 1]` to `[1, 18, 18, 64]`.

At this step, you should write:

```
# Vectorize
_dense1 = tf.reshape(_pool_dr2, [1, 18*18*64])
```

You also should replace your matrix `wd1` with:

```
'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([18*18*64, 1024], stddev=0.1))
```

---

In general in these situations, you need to print each shape, step after step, and realize **by yourself** where the shape doesn't correspond to what you expect.

Comment: After trying your code, it now says 'ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 16) for Tensor u'Reshape_3:0', which has shape '(1,)''

Comment: Oh also, I have a batch size of 1 and num_classes is 16

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell from what you provided, but it seems like you feed inputs with a batch size of 6, but only provide one label for them. Where does your data come from?